# Stopping a windows service via command line, where the service has symbols in it

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, windows-service

For whatever reason the company who installed this service used the same name for the display and the service name.

Which is this format (not exact wording to protect them)

"Blah® Blah™ Agent Service"

When I look at the properties of the service from the gui it shows both for display and service.

If I look at the service name from command line it shows this

"Blahr BlahT Agent Service"

However when I use the latter in a command line or bat, windows says invalid service.

If I copy and paste the name with symbols into a notepad with net stop in front of it and convert to bat file I get the same error.

So my question is how can I stop this service due to it having some symbols in the display and service name?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried single quotes around the service name?

Comment: I tried double quotes and no quotes at all.

Should I try - net stop 'Blahr BlahT Agent Service'      ?

Comment: Do or do not, there is no try.

Comment: You might also try the Powershell counterpart.

Comment: If you copy and paste from the GUI directly to the command line, does it work?  In the case of a batch file, you might need to take steps to ensure the batch file is appropriately encoded, probably UTF-16.

Comment: just tried both.  With single quotes it tells me my syntax is wrong.

Comment: @HarryJohnston ok! so copying from gui and pasting in command line works with double quotes.  When I paste it replaces the registered mark with an r and the Trademark with a T.  So is this an encoding issue with notepad?

Comment: Sounds like it.  Might be worth trying notepad++ or another third-party text editor.  Or even Wordpad might work, I suppose.  You'll probably need to use Save As and explicitly specify a suitable encoding.

Comment: alright so I copied the name from gui, placed in notepad ++ and have tried all these encodings. ANSI, UTF-8, UTF-8-BOM, UCS-2 BE BOM, UCS-2 LE BOM.  None of these worked.  What would the encode be?

Comment: Darn, looks like batch files don't support Unicode, see the [first comment under this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28413570/886887).  Try Powershell instead, as @Davidw suggested.  (Or you could try to find a code page that supports the particular characters you need.)